# Testing BlackBerry code without starting the device simulator

Tags: testing, blackberry, simulator, program-entry-point

In Eclipse, I want to test some java microedition network code -- javax.microedition.io.HttpConnection -- to see if the network connection is successful and get some cookie values. But running this code using a JRE on my development machine doesn't execute the method, unless I launch and test using a simulator.

Can I run BlackBerry code using a desktop JRE or will I always have to test using a simulator?

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard of a way of running BB code without running the simulator. You can set a program to automatically start the simulator and "click" some buttons so you can run tests automatically, but I don't think this is what you're looking for...